# How to allow 'Select none' from dropdown properly

Tags: dropdown, web

I'd like to allow selecting `none` from a dropdown menu (web).
On the other hand, there are no labels so I would like to also let the user know what the dropdown is for.

What's a good way of achieving this?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmssoL.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Separate the UX concern from the implementation concern

From the UX perspective, what you are looking for is a  [placeholder](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-placeholders/). Placeholders are by definition non selectable.

Your real problem is how to *implement* the placeholder in a non-selectable way.   That is beyond the scope of UX stackexchange, but [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box) shows a way to do it.

---

*BTW having no labels in a form and relying on placeholders only is an anti-pattern so should be used with care....the Nielsen article referenced above outlines why.*

Answer (score 1):

**One way** could be to place a little [x] next to the select element

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUgB2z.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Clicking that [x] will act as *select none* you can see it in action in my [yadcf plugin showcaes](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html) (next to each column filter - including select elements)

**Another way** is to do something similar to select2 plugin (placing that [x] button inside the selected element) see it action in the [fifth column filter in the showcase](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_select2.html) select any element and notice how the select looks like

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvBDZ8.png)</sup>

**Third** variation of the [x] button would be to show it *on hover* over the select element - see it in action in [the following sample](http://themes.laborator.co/#theme=xenon) (scroll down to the *Custom column filtering* section and hover over any of the table headers

Comment: The question is about labeling the dropdown values, not about a way to reset the dropdown menu.

Comment: @Marvin , I don't see that question as a *labeling question* at all, *Select none* is referring to a way of clearing the selection after a selection was made, that's my opinion about this question.

Comment: You are right, I probably misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. You understood the question but I feel like @tohstr s answer is better because it makes me reexamine the problem and make a better design

Answer (score 0):

you can use a plugin like Chosen http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/